# validation for allowing money value in datagridview cell like 12.50 in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am  working with datagridview control. I want to validate dataGridView to allow the value in money format in datagridview textbox cell like `123.00,123.50`.
That should take numeric values and one . value.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I have used in the past (and the only way that I know how to do it) is to create classes that inherit from DataGridViewTextBoxColumn and DataGridViewTextBoxCell, and use the derived class instead of DataGridViewTextBoxColumn as the ColumnType when creating the grid.

This [link](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/152435.aspx) has an example of how to do it in VB. I can't post my C# code as it was developed by a company I used to work for, but the VB code is basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
1. There should be a decimal.
2. Only 2 digits after decimal
3. And there should be 2 such numbers separated by a comma(,)
```

Here is the code:-
aspx file

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMoney" runat="server" Width="100px" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvMoney" ValidationGroup="Insert" runat="server"
ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="Please Enter value for money" ToolTip="Please Enter valid value for money"
SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="reMoney" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMoney"
ErrorMessage="Please Enter a Valid value for Money" ToolTip="Please Enter a Valid Value for money"
SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\d+([.])\d\d([,])\d+([.])\d\d"
                            ValidationGroup="Insert">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Code Behind i.e. aspx.cs file

```
if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert"))
        {
            eInfo.money = ((TextBox)gvEG.FindControl("txtMoney")).Text;
            new mainSQL().insertEmployeeInfo(eInfo); //My cs file for insert values to table
            FillEmployeeGrid();
        }
```

I have tried this code in my project and it is working properly.

The main code here is the Regular Expression:

```
ValidationExpression="\d+([.])\d\d([,])\d+([.])\d\d"
```

where

```
\d- denotes 1 digit
\d+ - one or many digits
\d\d - denotes only 2 digits
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like you want to validate user input in real time, I think the best and the effective way to go about it is creating a custom column type hosting a `MaskedtextBox`. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26005/DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox) article shows how to do it. And you can specify a format there. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) MSDN post to know about Mask Elements.